# Laravel Eloquent count and groupBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a vehicle table.

```
|id|name  |type |
|1 |BMW   |Car  |
|2 |volvo |Truck|
|3 |ducati|Bike |
```

What I want is...

```
|total|type |
|1    |Car  |
|1    |Truck|
|1    |Bike |
```

How can I `select count(type) as total, type from vehicle groupBy type` in Eloquent?

This is what I've tried but I get the below error.

```
$vehicle = DB::table("vehicles")->select(count("type"), "type")
    ->groupBy("type")->get();
```

**Error**

> count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string
> given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a "Vehicle" model? If so...

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::selectRaw('count(type) as total, type')
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->get();
```

If not, you can do it this way.

```
$vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
    ->selectRaw('count(type) as total, type')
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ahh thanks, last time i tried with your second option with only select, not selectRaw, the error is ` column 'count(type)' not found`